# Select most recent rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

So, my problem is inserted in this context:
I have a system for managing student applications for extra-curricular courses. These applications are stored in a table with the following structure:

- StudentId: the id of the student **[Primary Key]**
- CourseId: the id of the course **[Primary Key]**
- StatusVerificationDate: the date when the status of the application was verified **[Primary Key]**
- Status: the current application status (it can be "In Progress", "Refused", "Admited")

My problem is: For each student and Course, I need to get the most recent row.

```
StudentId CourseId StatusVarificationDate     Status
1         1001     2011-12-12 07:27:24  In Progress
1         1001     2011-12-12 09:27:24  In Progress
1         1002     2011-12-13 15:27:24  Admited
2         1001     2011-12-12 09:27:24  In Progress
2         1001     2011-12-12 15:27:24  Admited
```

With the above example, how can I get this result?

```
StudentId CourseId StatusVerificationDate     Status
1         1001     2011-12-12 09:27:24  In Progress
1         1002     2011-12-13 15:27:24  Admited
2         1001     2011-12-12 15:27:24  Admited
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/lUmelWO.png okay then

Comment: I'm new here, sorry, next time I will post my tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ROW_NUMBER()** with **Partition** as below:

```
;With T AS
(
    SELECT
        *,          
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StudentId,CourseId ORDER BY StatusVarificationDate DESC) AS PartNo
    FROM @tblTest   
)
SELECT
    *   
FROM T
WHERE PartNo=1
```

Comment: I think it should be `PARTITION BY StudentId, CourseId`

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I don't have so many experience in sql, so 'partition' is new to me. can you give me a brief explanation about why you are using this keyword in this query?

Comment: Partition will work like group by on your specify column and Row_Number will give index start from 1 to total item in your group (Partition)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually handled using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by StudentId, CourseId
                                order by StatusVarificationDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX aggregate function in JOIN statement :

```
 SELECT *
 FROM table1  
 JOIN
 (
    SELECT StudentId, CourseId MAX(StatusUpdateDate) Maxdate
    FROM table1    
 ) A ON A.Maxdate = StatusUpdateDate AND A.StudentId = table1.StudentId
```